# What does facebook api returns when requesting something the user is forbidden from doing?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

We all know that Facebook can "punish" a user by blocking him from sending messages, posting on his profile, doing reactions on posts... or any kind of a punishment.

When My application wants to do some action on behalf of the user and that action is forbidden for this user to do. what does the Graph API return?

For example:

If the user is banned by Facebook, because of some kind of spamming reports, from posting on his timeline for 7 or 30 days. and then my application wants to post something on his behalf, what kind of forbidden error will graph API return?

Comment: FYI: Your app can’t post on any user’s personal timeline via API any more, the necessary permission `publish_actions` has been removed.

Comment: well, it's just an example :) ..